# Unable to verify iPhone Developer Apps

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7-beta4

I am using Xcode 7 beta 4 and iOS 9. I'm having trouble in launching my app on my device using the new feature that Xcode 7 has, that allows us to try applications without having an Apple Developer Program

Here's what I get from Profile when I try to trust and verify apps. It keep telling me that I need to connect to the internet but I'm always connected. I try to delete my profile and my app and restarting my phone but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: any luck? Did you get it work?

Comment: I have the same problem :(

Comment: I just rest my iPhone to get it work :( so you may need to do some backup

Comment: Can anyone explain me what exactly happens when I press "Verify App" on that screen? How exactly my app gets verified through network?

Answer (score 4):

Just had this problem as well, it turned out that our network was blocking https://ppq.apple.com, which appears to be what iOS uses for verification. I guess it's also possible that the URL could be down as well sometimes.

Comment: ppq.apple.com has been down for about two hours now.

Comment: I am also facing this issue since last 3 hours... its still down :( any workaround for this?

Comment: I just ran into same issue and when i switched to another network the device was able to verify. It was a connection or blocked url

Answer (score 0):

If you locate in China, North Korea or other countries which have a `Great Firewall of China` like `Firewall`, 
it may block your network to some foreign website, so you can not verify your app.

What you need do is, download a `shadowrocket` in `app store`, it may cost a few dollars.

after download the `shadowrocket`, you should found a way to buy `vpn` account, the way of buying the `vpn` is very easy to found, you just need search `vpn` in `google`.

You open the `vpn` in your `shadowrocket`, you can access the blocking website, and you can verify your apps!